# Memory leaking because I have to retrieve data from UserDefault whenever re-present TableView

Tags: arrays, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a TableView, each cell has a picture taken from screenshot, I can edit the picture just like iPhone markup feature.

I save them locally with an array `[pictureStruct]` where each `pictureStruct` has things like `ID`, `name`, `UIImage`, etc.

I created the tableView base on `[pictureStruct]` like:

```
   let pictureStructArr = UserDefaults.standard.getStructArray(SImage.self, forKey: Keys.listImage)

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return pictureStructArr.count 
    }
```

So whenever I get back to the tableView, I have to do

```
self.pictureStructArr = UserDefaults.standard.getStructArray(SImage.self, forKey: Keys.listImage)
```

again to update the tableView, where it got memory leak each time.

How to prevent it happens?

Answer (score 0):

First you can't store images in user defaults, user defaults is for smallest type of data, like bools or int's, strings(something: boolean for isUserLogedIn). Never store structs with any properties in user defaults, use core data or your base on server, user defaults can't handle those in some point and app will crash.
Second please provide a little bit more info about code and what are you doing(like cell for at and what kind of extension on user defaults is getstructArray)